# Watson-Williams Test in R Circular

Tags: r

I'm using the circular package for R to do some Watson-Williams tests for homogeneity of simulated data sets. The test checks the assumption that the parameter of concentration is high (Batchelet's 1981 book Circular Statistics in Biology describes the assumption as *K*>2).

My problem is that I'm getting a warning that my "Global concentration parameter" is less than 2, even if my simulated data has *K*>2.

What is the Global concentration parameter, and how does this differ from *K*?

Here is my code:

```
 #create 1st directional angles 
 angles1<- deg(rvm(200, 90, 3))  #n=200, mean angle = 90 degrees, K = 3
 #create 2nd directional angles 
 angles2<- deg(rvm(200, 90, 3))   
 watson.williams.test(list(angles1,angles2))
```

and here is the warning:

```
Warning message: In watson.williams.test.default(x, group) :  Global concentration parameter: 0.151 < 2. The test is probably not applicable
```

Comment: Just to tell that I'm having the same issue.

Comment: This does not answer your question, but may solve it. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/265865/comparisons-of-circular-means/265950#265950